# GXT number field autocalculation

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a form in GXT with three number fields: weight, height and BMI. What I want to do is to calculate BMI automatically after filling weight and height fields by the user. Any ideas how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a keyListener on the two fields and in the listener override the keyPress() method and do you computations in it.